# OnClickListener error: "[..] invoke virtual method [...] on a null object reference", athough string declared

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm simply trying to use 2 buttons in my MainActivity. One opens a website (which works), the other should directly jump into my second class (which for simplification here, I only set as a second website). However, although button setup is similar to other button, using setOnClickListener as well as variable defined in resources, I'm receiving the error message below. 
I already excluded several fragments -  the error message seems to be concerning the button for accessing the 2nd class.

Apologies for getting lost with those trivialities...I'm lost but grateful for any hint.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{paperpad.app/paperpad.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="logo">Logo</string>
    <string name="app_name">PaperPad2</string>
    <string name="button_go2activity">Start Drawing</string>
    <string name="button_openPicture">Load Picture</string>
    <string name="button_closePicture">Stop</string>
    <string name="button_help">help</string>
    <string name="websiteAddress">PaperPad.app</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package paperpad.app;
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
//etc.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button_openHelp = findViewById(R.id.button_openHelp);    
        button_openHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                  
                Intent openHelp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com"));     
                startActivity(openHelp);
            }
        });
        Button button_go2activity = findViewById(R.id.button_go2activity);    
        button_go2activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                  
                Intent openLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));      
                startActivity(openLink);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_paperpad" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_openPicture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_titel"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_go2activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="269dp"
        android:text="@string/button_go2activity"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_openHelp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_openHelp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/button_help"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linkWebsite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_go2activity" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linkWebsite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="@string/websiteAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_openHelp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not in the `activity_main` layout xml (currently). If in a fragment, it has not been loaded yet.

If it's defined in a fragment you should move this code to the fragment.

Comment: May you please further specify your answer? Both buttons are in MainActivity.java. As far as I understand, I'm not using fragments.

Comment: I added my activity_main.xml for a better understanding. All buttons, one after another, are listed there and therefore should be found by the setonclicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare Buttons on class level and initialize them later:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button_openHelp;
Button button_go2activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_openHelp = findViewById(R.id.button_openHelp);    
    button_openHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                  
            Intent openHelp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com"));     
            startActivity(openHelp);
        }
    });
    button_go2activity = findViewById(R.id.button_go2activity);    
    button_go2activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                  
            Intent openLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));      
            startActivity(openLink);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Buttons are already declared as strings in the strings.xml. If I add them as described, the error message 'field button never used', if I understood correctly what you meant. Many thanks non the less.

Comment: Made it a bit more clear by posting the whole class. Try to copy and run if this works.

Comment: Dear Otto, thanks a lot for your efforts.  Unfortunately this still returns the error "Attempt to invoke virtual method xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx on a null object reference'. i admit being a bit clueless...sorry. It should work...

Comment: Just copied your code into a new Android Studio Project and it just runs fine, opening both URLs....

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I guess there's an issue with android studio. Will try to (a) update and, if needed, (b) re-install. If the code works I'll immediately mark your answer as "working".